# R scatter.smooth function - how to change labels of the x-axis from numbers to categorical variables?

Tags: r, plot, smoothing, scatter

I am really new to R and English is not my mothertongue. I have a dataset ("data") loaded to R: one variable is the effect size (which should be plottet on the y-axis, this works very well), but the other one is categorical and contains countries like "USA", "Indonesia". These countries should be written on the x-axis. They are already given in the dataset under the name "Countries". I tried this:

```
scatter.smooth(data$Countries, data$r, ylab="effect size (r)", xlab="countries", span=.95)
```

But I get 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 ... etc. on the x-axis. How can I force R to use my already given labels in this column of the dataset? Also the right amount of labels?

Thank you for your help

Comment: A smooth scatter does not make sense with a categorical x axis. Your points will smooth out on the x axis too. Have you tried `boxplot` instead of `scatter.smooth`?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can´t decide to choose boxplot over scatter.smooth, as I am writing a master thesis and I "should" use scatter.smooth for all my variables, as a visualisation of the effect size. But maybe I got this wrong and you are right and it doesn´t make any sense with Lowess /Loess.